# How to get the non Equal values from String Array in java..?

Tags: java, arrays

```
String[] mT={"A","B"};
    String[] mT2={"A","BB","C","A","B","C","C","A","D","F","B"};

    for(int i=0;i<mT.length;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<mT2.length;j++)
        {
            if(mT[i].equals(mT2[j]))
            {
                System.out.println("Equal Values are :"+mT2[j]);
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println(" Not- Equal Values are :"+mT2[j]);
            }
        }
    }
```

output :

Equal Values are :A

Not- Equal Values are :BB

Not- Equal Values are :C

Equal Values are :A

Not- Equal Values are :B

Not- Equal Values are :C

Not- Equal Values are :C

Equal Values are :A

Not- Equal Values are :D

Not- Equal Values are :F

Not- Equal Values are :B

Not- Equal Values are :A

Not- Equal Values are :BB

Not- Equal Values are :C

Not- Equal Values are :A

Equal Values are :B

Not- Equal Values are :C

Not- Equal Values are :C

Not- Equal Values are :A

Not- Equal Values are :D

Not- Equal Values are :F

Equal Values are :B

i'm getting duplicates values, how can i avoid the duplicates for not-equals.. any one help me. thanks in advance.. :)

Comment: ..because Inner for loop iterates two times

Comment: Maybe using `Set`s and some sort of `union` operation would be a neat solution.

Comment: What exactly do you want to achieve?

Comment: thanks for your reply.. i need not equals values..

Comment: i'm getting not equals values but it have a duplicates..  i want avoid that

Comment: Could you use Lists or Sets (no duplicates) instead of arrays? Because they provide methods that could help you, such as retainAll and removeAll.

Comment: do u have any examples

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add those to an arraylist by checking whether it contains the object

```
ArrayList<String> array =  new ArrayList<String>();
for(int i=0;i<mT.length;i++)
{
    for(int j=0;j<mT2.length;j++)
    {
        if(mT[i].equals(mT2[j]))
        {
            System.out.println("Equal Values are :"+mT2[j]);
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println(" Not- Equal Values are :"+mT2[j]);
             if(!array.contains(mT2[j]) // checking whether the arraylist contains the object
                 array.add(mT2[j]); // adding the content to arraylist. Now it will not contain duplicates
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: one thing.. it also show the first array value of A and B., how can i eliminate those values

Comment: output :  not equals : BB
not equals : C
not equals : B
not equals : D
not equals : F
not equals : A